# How to change contact form 7 Redirecting URL dynamically - WordPress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am building a website for one of my clients and they want a function into their website some thing like the following:

when people click the download link, a form will appear ( contact form 7) and after visitors put their details , it will re-directed to the download link.

I able to re-direct to a new page after form submission by using following additional setting to the contact form 7.

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://example.com/';"
```

[image]

However, They have 10 files , I need to change the re-direction link 10 times to trigger the download for the appropriate file. I can do it by using 10 contact forms which will be very dirty.

**Is there any way i can change the re-direction URL dynamically?**

For example,

```
http://example.com/?id=1
http://example.com/?id=2

<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];

$url= "http://example.com/id=?". $id; 


?>
```

is there any way to change the following Location with $url ?

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://example.com/';"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found a way to change the redirection URL dynamically. I have followed the following steps to achieve the dynamic redirection:

1. In contact form 7's Additional setting put the following:

   on_sent_ok: 'redirect();'
2. We need a hidden field to carry a piece of necessary information. However, Contact form 7 by default do not allow us to create hidden fields. The developer SevenSpark has developed an extension to allow hidden fields in Contact form 7.
   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/
   please download the plugin and install. you will see two new tags have been generated for the contact form 7. this will allow you to grab the value from $_GET variable. please check the details on plugin page.

   ex. http://example.com/?foo="bar"
3. Create a template page or exiting page template ok.
4. assign the template to the appropriate page. if you want to use the default template you do not need to create or assign any template.
5. open your template file in an Editor.
6. paste the following code:

   ```
   <script>    

       function redirect() {



           // your hidden field ID
              var filename = document.getElementById('redFilename').value;

           var url ='';

           //alert(document.getElementById('redFilename').value);
           if (filename == 'apple')
           {


               url= 'http://example.com/thankyou/';


           }
           else if (filename == 'orange')
           {
            url= 'http://example.com/thankyou_orange/';
           }    


    window.location = url;

           }
           </script>
   ```
7. Now browse the link with GET parameter.

   ex. http://example.com/?redFilename="apple"

the hidden field of the contact form 7 will capture the redFilename value. if form submission is successful, it will redirect to the http://example.com/thankyou_orange/ page

Enjoy!!!!

Comment: Thank you for sharing this - I am also looking for similar thing. But one question: what is stopping the user from directly entering the "final destination" url? For example, http://example.com/thankyou_orange/    - How to prohibit it and make the user fill the contact form mandatory?

Comment: From the CR7 [FAQ on redirects](https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/) `on_sent_ok` is going to be removed in 2017, but the `redirect` function should still apply to the new `wpcf7mailsent` event mentioned in the same FAQ

Answer (score 3):

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'ip_wpcf7_mail_sent');
function ip_wpcf7_mail_sent($wpcf7)
{
    $on_sent_ok = $wpcf7->additional_setting('ip_on_sent_ok', false);

    if (is_array($on_sent_ok) && count($on_sent_ok) > 0)
    {
        wp_redirect(trim($on_sent_ok[0]));
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: `on_sent_ok` is [going to be removed in 2017](https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/)

Comment: From what I can tell from my attempts, this doesn't work because the CF7 form submits via AJAX, and so this just redirects that AJAX request. That means that the AJAX never returns a response and the CF7 form updating spinner never stops

Comment: It will work if you [turn off the CF7 JavaScript](https://contactform7.com/loading-javascript-and-stylesheet-only-when-it-is-necessary/)

Answer (score 0):

`on_sent_ok:` never worked for me.

I tried something like this for tracking conversation.

```
  var sent = $('#wpcf7-f3224-o1').find('.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok');

   if ( sent.length ) {
       <?php
           $page_name = get_the_title();
           $the_name = str_replace(' ', '',  $page_name);
        ?>
       self.location="/merci/?page=<?php echo $the_name ?>";
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

Contact form 7 Redirecting to Another URL After Submissions 2017 Updates

First you need to update contact form 7 on new version i try it on v7.4.9 and then place a contact form short code in any page and place this JS script any where on page and change url where need to redirect your page after submission

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
location = 'http://example.com/';
}, false );
</script>
```

For more info click contact form 7 official site  https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/

Comment: Where as this is true, this doesn't answer the concept of redirecting to a *dynamic* URL

Comment: you need to update your contact form 7 plugin to use this script as i mention  above  i try it on v7.4.9 and then place a contact form short code in any page and place this JS script any where on page and change url in JS where need to redirect your dynamic page after submission

Comment: If you read the question, the person asking can already do this, but they explicitly don't want to have to change the form for every page. They want to use part of the GET request or perhaps the variables submitted in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I went down the Javascript route, which works... but you then don't have access to the submitted variables (at least I couldn't see how you would). Here I have ported my Javascript code across to PHP code.

You can access any hidden or displayed inputs in the form and use them to build the URL.

There is one required trick to do the redirect in PHP rather than Javascript, which is that you have to [turn off the CF7 Javascript as per the doc](https://contactform7.com/loading-javascript-and-stylesheet-only-when-it-is-necessary/). Put this in your `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WPCF7_LOAD_JS', false);
```

Then you can put this in your theme `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'icc97_so_mail_sent', 10, 3);

/**
 * Ported Javascript code to redirect the CF7 form
 *
 * Have to do it in PHP because we want access to the POSTed data
 *
 * There is a further complication that the default CF7 submission is AJAX
 * Then our WP redirect doesn't do anything
 * So we have to turn off the CF7 Javascript via wp-config.php
 *
 */
function icc97_so_mail_sent( $contact_form ) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    // example data:
    // {"_wpcf7":"11684","_wpcf7_version":"4.9","_wpcf7_locale":"en_GB","_wpcf7_unit_tag":"wpcf7-f11684-p11681-o1","_wpcf7_container_post":"11681","your-name":"Ian","your-organisation":"Stack Overflow","your-email":"ian@example.com","your-agreement":"1"}

    /**
     * Get an attribute value from the CF7 form
     *
     * @param  string $name attribute name
     * @return string       attribute value
     */
    $attr = function($name) use ($data) {
        $val = $data[$name];
        // Dropdown / select values are arrays could be a one element array
        return is_array($val) ? $val[0] : $val;
    };

    /**
     * Create URL for downloads page
     *
     * @param  string $domain e.g. https://example.com, can be blank for relative
     * @param  array  $names  attributes
     * @return string         URL e.g. https://example.com/downloads/x/x/x/?data=xxx
     */
    $buildUrl = function ($domain, $names) use ($attr) {
        $stub = [$domain, 'downloads'];
        // we want lower case, attributes
        $path = array_map('strtolower', array_map($attr, $names));

        // create an array of the full URL and then join with '/'
        return join('/', array_merge($stub, $path));
    };

    $domain = '';
    // this requires AJAX to be turned off - see function doc block
    \wp_redirect($buildUrl($domain, ['your-name', 'your-organisation']));
    // exit otherwise CF7 forces it's own redirect back to the original page
    exit;
}
```